# Passing the results of first CompleteableFuture to another CompletableFuture down the chain

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have an async method that returns `CompletableFuture<ClassA>`.

```
private CompletableFuture<ClassA> asyncA(..)
```

I'm exposing a public method that must return `CompleteableFuture<ClassB>` that is based on data from class A. The caller to this method should not be aware of ClassA:

```
return asyncA(..)
       .thenApply(objectA -> return new ObjectB(objectA.getName());
```

Up to this point all is working as expected.

Now I like to perform an async operation after there is an ObjectB result and call to a void method `asyncC` , and I like to somehow pass it  objectA:

```
return asyncA(..)
       .thenApply(objectA -> return new ObjectB(objectA.getName())
       .thenRunAsync(asyncC(objectA));
```

But it seems like the `objectA` is not defined within the `thenRunAsync`.

Is there a way to perform such operation?

Comment: new ObjectB() is not used anymore?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov no. ObjectB is not used down the chain, but only used by the caller to the method

Comment: please write an equivalent synchronous program so that we could understand what you want. Something like ClassA objectA = asyncA().get(); ObjectB objectB=new ObjectB(objectA.getName()); asyncC(objectA);

Answer (score 0):

So we came up with this solution:

```
return asyncA(..)
   .thenApply(objectA -> {
       CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> asyncC(objectA));
       return new ObjectB(objectA.getName())
      })
```

Comment: In your question, you said you want “to perform an async operation **after** there is an ObjectB result”, so how can your solution be to perform the action before or even concurrently to the construction of the `ObjectB`  result?